# I have a loop which relies on a loss function. I want to find the optimal point which it stops, here is my idea

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am writing a neural network using tensorflow which modifies an image to imitate a style of art. There is a loss function which defines how close one image is to the other image, what I am doing is trying to iterate, modifying each updated image to be further like the style of art I'm trying to implement, until I've reached the optimal image.

What I am doing is storing the loss in an array and using numpy I'm getting the mean and standard deviation. Then at the beginning of each loop I check the latest loss function against the current mean *minus* one half standard deviation. If it is less than or equal to this number it continues, if not it stops looping.

My question is will this loop ever stop?

Here is my code:

```
            while(min_value <= np.mean(min_value_array) - np.std(min_value_array) * (1/2)):
                x, min_value, info = fmin_l_bfgs_b(evaluator.loss, x,
                                                 fprime=evaluator.grads, maxfun=20)
                min_value_array = np.append(min_value_array, min_value)
                print('Current loss value:', min_value, "must be lower than or equal to", np.mean(min_value_array) - np.std(min_value_array) * (1/2))
                # Save current generated image
                img = x.copy().reshape((targetSize[0], targetSize[1], 3))
                img_to_save = deprocess_image(img)
                fname = path_to_save_styles+image_name+"-"+img_style + '_at_iteration_%d.png' % i
                i += 1
```

Answer: Yes it stops.

Updated question: Is this the optimal stopping point?

Comment: Hi! I am not sure about whether it will be called an optimal point or not as there seems to be no usage of gradient descent of loss with respect to content image . Did you check this link on total variation loss from style transfer to confirm your results though? https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/style_transfer#total_variation_loss